# What other names could be considered during the lookup for a namespace-name, different than namespace names?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, language-lawyer, name-lookup

§3.4.6/1:

> In a *using-directive* or *namespace-alias-definition*, during the
>   lookup for a *namespace-name* or for a name in a
>   *nested-name-specifier* only namespace names are considered.

Basically, what I'm asking is: "why is this paragraph necessary?"

Answer (score 2):

[Defect report 373: Lookup on namespace qualified name in using-directive](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3160.html#373) gives an example of why the wording matters:

```
namespace X {
  namespace Y {
    struct X {
      void f()
      {
        using namespace X::Y;
        namespace Z = X::Y;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Which `X` is being referred to in `using namespace X::Y` the struct or the namespace? Without that wording in `3.4.6` it would be ambiguous.

This actually lead to the change in the wording from:

> When looking up a namespace-name in a using-directive or namespace-alias-definition, only namespace names are considered.

to what we have today because the original wording did not cover the *nested-name-specifier*.

The ambiguity is with the *nested-name-specifier* which if we look at the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) the grammar in section `5.1.1` *General* is as follows:

```
nested-name-specifier:
    ::opt type-name ::
    ::opt namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier templateopt simple-template-id ::
```

and the following paragraphs which I won't copy since they are large do not restrict *nested-name-specifier* to a *namespace*.

As far as I can tell section `7.3.1` *Namespace definition* sufficiently restricts *namespace-name* to prevent ambiguities.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding the ambiguity. The _using-directive_ and the _namespace-alias-definition_, both refer to a namespace, not a class name.

Answer (score 1):

Clang's unit tests for `namespace using` and `alias directives` is exactly the answer to your question:

> clang-cc -fsyntax-only -verify %s

```
struct ns1 {}; // This is not a namespace, although a namespace has ns1 as a name
void ns2();
int ns3 = 0;

namespace ns0 {
  namespace ns1 {
    struct test0 {};
  }
  namespace ns2 {
    struct test1 {};
  }
  namespace ns3 {
    struct test2 {};
  }
}

using namespace ns0;

namespace test3 = ns1; // don't get confused
namespace test4 = ns2;
namespace test5 = ns3;

using namespace ns1; // don't get confused
using namespace ns2;
using namespace ns3;

test0 a;
test1 b;
test2 c;
```

This issue has also been discussed in [n3160 defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3160.html)